# How does conda channel resolve?

Tags: anaconda, conda

I am trying to use conda and is unclear on how the conda channels work. From the documentation, I can see that channels are essentially just repositories, so if I say

```
conda install -c r r-essentials
```

It will install r-essentials from the r repository. However, if I don't specified the repository, or specify a repostory that doesn't contain the package

```
conda install -c conda r-essentials
```

Conda repository doesn't have r-essentials, so now it's attempting to try the different repository using flexible resolve. I think this is the part that confused me. How does it know which repository to try. If I examine my .condarc, all I see is:

```
channels:
  - defaults
```

It doesn't have a list of channels to try unless defaults itself is a list of channels. The other issue is that I added the following line to .condarc

```
channel_priority: strict
```

Dispite the entry and even restarting the terminal, conda still use the flexible method.  I guess my question is more about how conda finds the repository and how it resolves it.